# REGEX ASP Classic Replace

Tags: regex, asp

Como posso pegar um texto grande cheios de ulrs e trasformá-las em links em ASP CLASSIC 3 usando REGEX? Queria adpatar esse código. Chega no replace ali em baixo não tenho ideia...

Essa Regex aí, casa todas as url, mas como substitu-las e trasforma-las em link?

```
texto="Lorem ipsum dolor www.stackoverflow.com sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"


Set regx = New RegExp
regx.IgnoreCase = True
regx.Global = True
regx.Pattern = "/(?:www\.|(?!www))[^\s\.]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[^\s]+\.[^\s]{2,}/gi"
texto_saida = regx.Replace(texto, "<a href='http$2://www$3.$4$5$6'>$1</a> ")

Set regx = Nothing

response.write texto_saida
```

Answer (score -1):

Tenta esse código

```
texto="Lorem ipsum dolor www.stackoverflow.com sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"
Set regx = New RegExp
regx.IgnoreCase = True
regx.Global = True
regx.Pattern = "([a-z]{3,})\.([a-z]{1,})\.([a-z\.]{1,})"
texto_saida = regx.Replace(texto, "<a href='http://$1.$2.$3'>$1.$2.$3</a> ")
Set regx = Nothing
response.write texto_saida
```